# How do I solve this logic question?

Tags: logic

I'm doing my logic tutorials. And I cannot understand what does this question want. Here it goes:

> What is the value of variable x after the statement
>
> > If $2+2 = 4$ then $x:= x+1$
>
> If $x=0$ before this statement in encountered?
>
> (The symbol $:=$ stands for assignment. The statement $x:x+1$ means assignment of the value of $x+1$ to $x$)

Thank you!

Comment: What do you find unclear in this question ?

Comment: Hint : $2+2=4$.

Comment: The logic is : "if *condition* is TRUE, then assign to variable $x$ the value $x+1$" and we know that the current value of $x$ is $0$.

Comment: @krirkrirk I cannot understand what does it want.

Comment: The "condition" is $2+2=4$; what is its truth value ?

Comment: @MelissaC. The question asks you to find the final value of $x$. You start with $x=0$ ; then, if $2+2=4$ is true, $x$ becomes $x+1$ (and if $2+2\neq 4$, nothing happens). What's the final value of $x$ ?

Comment: @krirkrirk does that mean the final value of $x$ is $1$?

Comment: Hint : $ 0+1=1$

Comment: @MelissaC. Yes! At first, $x=0$. Since $2+2$ is indeed equal to $4$, $x$ becomes $x+1$, that is : $x$ becomes $0+1=1$.

Comment: @krirkrirk if that's the case, is the truth value true or false?

Comment: @Timkinsella It does stand for assignement in a programming context ; but it's fairly used in maths as a way to define a notation. E.g : let $\Delta := b^2-4ac$

Comment: The context of the question unquestionably is that the quoted "statement" is a bit of computer program, and you're supposed to predict what the program will do. If you've never seen such notation in the course where you're given the question, you may be the unwitting subject of a "camel has two humps"-type experiment.

Comment: @krirkrirk: In this particular case, where the symbol $x$ appear (in an apparently inconsistent way) on both two sides of $:=$, I think it can only be meant as destructive assignment.

Comment: @MelissaC. What truth value ? You seem a little bit confused, this question is not a logic statement that is either true or false, it's more of an algorithm.

Comment: @krirkrirk oh yes, was confused just now. Sorry about that. Now I have everything cleared up. Thank you!